# C#: Best practice for obfuscating password in text file?

Tags: c#, passwords, obfuscation, password-protection

Firefox has to store passwords. That is totally unsafe, but it has to do it, that's all.
My C# app has the same requirement (it is a kind of browser).

Rather than storing passwords in plaintext, Firefox obfuscates them a bit.
What is the best practice for this kind of obfuscation?

For instance, here is Firefox's strategy, if I understand well:

- Create a salt for the app's user
- For each password, use the salt in a symmetric transformation when storing/retrieving
- Store the passwords file in a directory named after the salt.

Is my understanding correct?
Is there any better strategy, or even a C# library for this?

[Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008304/password-file-obfuscation) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982260/obfuscate-strings-in-python) for other programming languages have unsatisfying answers, they don't not go as far as Firefox, just suggesting rot13 or base64, which makes it easy for automated malware to identify obfuscated passwords in unknown software. (just searching for the base64 value of common passwords)

*Once again: it will not resist to any attacker, I know. But if [Firefox cares](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=357473) I should too.*

Comment: What you want exists within the .NET just use any number of secured password hashing algorithms.  There are hundreds of examples on the internet that explain how to do this.

Comment: It is not very safe to take security advise from strangers on the internet :)

Comment: @Ramhound: It sounds like he needs to be able to retrieve them later.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you use OAuth? Can you use a challenge-response scheme with a zero-knowledge proof?

Comment: Unless your application requires users to log-in against it, you should not bother with a so-called user-friendly feature for saving passwords. So should Firefox do. The safest place where to save a password is a brain, not a file system.

Comment: @SLaks: Unfortunately, users have to connect to servers that do not understand OAuth. What I am trying to accomplish is a CMIS automatic synchronization tool: http://cmissync.github.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [`ProtectedData` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) to encrypt the passwords.

You can specify `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` to encrypt data using the current user's Windows login password, so that no other user can decrypt it (this also works if the user has no password)

Comment: Just as a clarification, it is not the User's Windows logon password, but the unique key tied to the user account. So if a user was deleted, recreating a new user with the same name and same password would not let you decrypt the data. But +1 anyway as ProtectedData is the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easiest to use an encryption rather than obfuscating.  Obfuscating code generally makes it harder for someone to identify what is what in code if they viewed the source.  If you don't encrypt the information however, people can still figure it out.

My advice would be is to use AES-256 or Tripple DES-128 Encryption.

Easily, you could have the passwords stored in a text file and then encrypted.  Only then through your browsers can the file be decrypted.

Comment: Where would you store the encryption key, Sublimity, or would you store it?

Comment: From what I understood by what he was saying:

Rather than storing passwords in plaintext, Firefox obfuscates them a bit.

I was suggesting that he could encrypt the passwords, yea the decryption key would be in the program.

The problem I see with the other person is what happens if the person uses their application on another computer and requires that password, they are out of luck.

It was an option.

Comment: +1 Interesting idea. Note: If the decryption key is stored in the program, then it is the same for everyone, which makes attack a little bit easier.

Comment: Yea, it's understandable but unless someone knows what they are looking for, chances are you won't be getting any random person finding the usernames/passwords.